# Insertar en código duro el resultado de un Select

Tags: sql-server, insert

A) tengo una tabla que se llama `[staging].[destino]` que es un simple repositorio de datos.

B) tengo una vista que se llama `[staging].[origen]` y que hace `UNION` de varias tablas.  Por la cantidad de registros y si se aplica un `select *` se tarda aproximadamente 2 minutos (este tiempo no es ningún problema).  B1)Esta vista contiene los datos que deseo trasladar previa aplicación de un filtro a `[staging].[destino]`.

C) tengo una tabla temporal `#mylist`. Es súper básica 3 campos y 5 registros.  C1) contiene la información a utilizar como filtro del inciso *B1)* y se modifica constantemente.

D) el script que estoy utilizando para trasladar los datos `[staging].[origen]` a `[staging].[destino]` aplicando el filtro requerido es:

```
INSERT INTO [staging].[destino]
   SELECT *
   FROM [staging].[oringen]
   WHERE db IN
   (
       SELECT DISTINCT
              db
       FROM #mylist
   )
```

PROBLEMA:

1) El inconveniente es que al ejecutar el script, la vista `[staging].[origen]` se ejecuta completa y después aplica al filtro. Así se tarda los 2 minutos.  1.1) incluso modifiqué el script original por este y se tarda siempre lo mismo ya que primero ejecuta la vista y luego aplica el filtro:

```
INSERT INTO [staging].[fact_enc_prueba]
   SELECT a.*
   FROM [staging].[fact_complementos_enc_prueba] a
        INNER JOIN #mylist b ON b.db = a.db
```

2)SIN EMBARGO, si modifico el script escribiendo en código duro el filtro **¡no se tarda ni 1 segundo!**:

```
INSERT INTO [staging].[destino]
   SELECT *
   FROM [staging].[oringen]
   WHERE db IN (1,7)
```

2.1)al ver el PLAN se aprecia que ejecuta la vista de una vez con el filtro.

*PREGUNTA*: alguna manera de insertar en código duro en `IN` el resultado del query de la tabla temporal de tal manera que mi `INSERT` dure **1 segundo y no 2 minutos??**

Comment: que motor usas?

Comment: El problema debe de estar en la vista. Intenta un `SELECT *
   FROM [staging].[oringen]` y ve si dura mucho.

Comment: sin ver las descripciones de las tablas es muy dificil.. probablemente #mylist haga un full scan de la tabla o algo asi que le cuesta mucho resolver. Por que no agregas el explain plan?

Comment: y por favor añade la etiqueta de la base de datos que usas si coresponde..

Comment: Volví a plantear la pregunta tratando de resolver los comentarios de todos...   de antemano gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a los que se interesaron por mi pregunta...   les cuento que al final lo logré resolver la situación...   simplemente le adicioné `IS NOT NULL` de la siguiente manera:

```
INSERT INTO [staging].[fact_enc_prueba]
   SELECT a.*
   FROM [staging].[fact_complementos_enc_prueba] a
        INNER JOIN #mylist b ON
         a.db IS NOT NULL -- **ACÁ**
         AND b.db = a.db;
```

Al adicionar esto, modificó el Plan y ya no hizo el barrido completo de la vista `[staging].[origen]` sino que simplemente fue a buscar los coincidentes, lográndose el objetivo deseado que se tardara **1 segundo** y NO 2 minutos.

Answer (score 0):

en #mylist, debe haber datos no repetitivos, es por esto que la cola se hace larga y gata mucho tiempo. Puedes probar en hacer una consulta tipo union dentro de los parámetros del insert para poder minimizar el tiempo y hacer mas cerrada las clausulas condicionales para que te haga una validación concreta y deseche los datos no relevantes.